# Asymptotic behavior of the integral involving gamma function

Tags: integration, asymptotics

Let $\Delta>0$ be fixed and define a function
$$ G(x) = 2^{2\Delta-1} \frac{e^{-x\pi/2}}{\Gamma(2\Delta)} \left| \Gamma\left(\Delta - i\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|^2,$$
where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function. The behavior of $G(x)$ is plotted as follows for $\Delta=0.3$:

[image]

It can be shown that as $x\to\infty$,
$$G(x)\sim \frac{2\pi}{\Gamma(2\Delta)}|x|^{2\Delta-1} e^{-\pi x}$$
decays exponentially, and as $x\to-\infty$, the function $G(x)$ behaves
$$G(x) \sim \frac{2\pi}{\Gamma(2\Delta)}|x|^{2h-1}.$$

I am interested in the behavior of the function
$$F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \: xG(x) (G(-x-y) + G(-x+y)), \quad y\in \mathbb R.$$
**Question**: What is the asymptotic behavior of the function $F(y)$ as $y\to \infty$?

**Remark**: Using the Mathematica, the behavior of $F(y)$ for $\Delta=0.3$ is:

[image]

Note that there is a spurious discontinuity around $y=500$, and Mathematica throws an error while evaluating the integral. Hence, the numerical result is not to be very trusted.

**Mathematica code for last plot**:

```
G[x_, \[CapitalDelta]_] = 
  2^(2 \[CapitalDelta] - 1) Exp[-x Pi/2]/
    Gamma[2 \[CapitalDelta]] Abs[Gamma[\[CapitalDelta] - I x/2]]^2;
    testint[y_, \[CapitalDelta]_] := 
     NIntegrate[
      x G[x, \[CapitalDelta] ] (G[-x - y, \[CapitalDelta]] + 
         G[-x + y, \[CapitalDelta]]), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 8 , Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
    yrange = Range[0, 600, 10];
    tab = Table[{y, testint[y, 0.3]}, {y, yrange}]
    ListPlot[tab, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Could you provide the syntax used for the generation of the last plot ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sure, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the key issue is the $0.3$. Replacing it by $\frac 3{10}$, no problem even for much larger values of $y$.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
y & F(y) \\
 0 & 0. \\
 250 & -16215.7 \\
 500 & -37253.9 \\
 750 & -60601.1 \\
 1000 & -85586.9 \\
 1250 & -111866. \\
 1500 & -139225. \\
 1750 & -167515. \\
 2000 & -196627. \\
 2250 & -226478. \\
 2500 & -257001. \\
 2750 & -288142. \\
 3000 & -319855. \\
 3250 & -352101. \\
 3500 & -384848. \\
 3750 & -418066. \\
 4000 & -451730. \\
 4250 & -485818. \\
 4500 & -520310. \\
 4750 & -555187. \\
 5000 & -590434. \\
 6000 & -734833. \\
 7000 & -884148. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very strangely, even I replaced the 0.3 to 3/10 in the above code, I have the same error and cannot reproduce your result ($F(y) \neq 0$ for $y>500$).  Still, in my code, $F(y) \approx 0$ for $y>500$.

Did you also change the NIntegrate options?